# Cosmos DB Emulator on Windows 11 - cannot create database

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, windows-11

I've installed the latest cosmos db emulator on my local Windows 11 machine by downloading and installing from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator

The emulator launches and runs at localhost:8081 like it should. I'm then trying to create a database using the following using the following (c#, .net 6.0, using nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` `3.31.2`)

```cs
var options = new CosmosClientOptions
{
    HttpClientFactory = () =>
    {
        HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator,
        };

        return new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
    },

    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
};

var client = new CosmosClient(
    "https://localhost:8081",
    "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
    options);

await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("MyDatabase");
```

When it gets to `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync`, I get the following timeout exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: RequestTimeout (408); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; 

Reason: (GatewayStoreClient Request Timeout. Start Time UTC:21/02/2023 10:32:58; Total Duration:39957.7417 Ms; Request Timeout 20000 Ms; Http Client Timeout:65000 Ms; Activity id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;);
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

I've followed the guidance on troubleshooting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-local-emulator), but still no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was successfully able to create database, when I tried to execute the code shared in the question with the exact same configuration(except connection value). It seems the error message you are getting of RequestTimeout (408) may be caused due to multiple factors like CPU exhaustion, thread starvation, low socket or port availability and failure rate that violates the Azure Cosmos DB SLA. To diagnose and troubleshoot issues with Cosmos DB .net SDK you can refer [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-request-timeout.md)